# Why doesn't Entity Framework use ObseravableCollection instead of ICollection?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So when I have a 1:many (or many:many) collection endpoint in a model, it's of type `ICollection<>`. Why doesn't Entity Framework use [`ObservableCollection<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0) so it can use those notifications to know when a collection has been modified?

Or at least provide this as an option so that when the model is instantiated, we can make use of the notifications in our code?

Not a biggie. And I'm guessing there is a very good reason this is not used nor an option. I am curious as to why.

Comment: You can freely use `ObservableCollection` as a navigation property. / Also take a look at [Notification entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#notification-entities).

Comment: That link is very helpful - I love getting the why behind it. (Better than just saying it's magic & works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexanderPetrov comment answered the question. Copied here to have it as an answer:

You can freely use ObservableCollection as a navigation property. / Also take a look at [Notification entities.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection#notification-entities)